# How to Customize Elementor Posts query for a custom field?

Tags: wordpress, elementor, posts

I am using wordpress & I want elementor posts widget to show only posts which belong to a category & which belong to a specific institute.

**Problem:** Category part can be done inside widget itself but filtering institute (custom field) is my problem.

---

**Solution I am trying:**

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/institute-query', function( $query ) {
$meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

// Append our meta query instead of overwriting all elementors own metaqueries
if($meta_query == ""){
    $meta_query = array();
}

// Append our meta query
$meta_query[] = [
    'key' => 'course_institution',
    'value' => [ 'University of Pennsylvania', 'university of pennsylvania', 'University-of-Pennsylvania', 'university-of-pennsylvania' ],
    'compare' => 'or',
];
$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `'compare' => 'IN',` insted of `'compare' => 'or',`

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/institute-query', function( $query ) {
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

    // Append our meta query instead of overwriting all elementors own metaqueries
    if( !is_array( $meta_query ){
        $meta_query = array();
    }

    // Append our meta query
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key'     => 'course_institution',
        'value'   => [ 'University of Pennsylvania', 'university of pennsylvania', 'University-of-Pennsylvania', 'university-of-pennsylvania' ],
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ];
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
} );
```

Comment: I did used OR but it does not seem to work either.